# SQL Server : syntax error

Tags: sql-server

I keep on having an error

> Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'SELECT'
>   Incorrect syntac near ')'

```
(SELECT TOP 5 t2.ItemID, SUM(t2.Quantity) 
 FROM Orders as t1
 as Quantity FROM t2.ItemID in 

 (SELECT ItemID FROM Orders as t1 INNER JOIN BasketItems as t2 on t2.BasketID = t1.BasketID

 WHERE t1.OrderStatusID = 3 AND t1.OrderDate BETWEEN '" + LastWeekDate + "' AND '" + TomorrowsdaysDate + "')

 GROUP BY t2.ItemID ORDER BY Quantity desc");
```

Comment: Post your BasketItems, Orders data structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing the  FROM section in the outer SELECT statement (line 2)

What you have in there is a WHERE condition

Also i dont think you need a sub query for this

try this

```
('  SELECT TOP 5 t2.ItemID, SUM(t2.Quantity)  as Quantity 
    FROM Orders as t1 
        INNER JOIN BasketItems as t2 on t2.BasketID = t1.BasketID
    WHERE t1.OrderStatusID = 3 
    AND t1.OrderDate BETWEEN '" + LastWeekDate + "' AND '" + TomorrowsdaysDate + "'
    GROUP BY t2.ItemID ORDER BY 2 desc
 ');
```